# Local weather app made with Typescript

Tags: json, promise, typescript

I would like feedback on my Local weather app. This site simply gets the local weather. I refactored it from jQuery to Typescript to try to learn more about Typescript.

Here is a demo: https://capozzic1.github.io/local_weather_app_v2/

Here is the index.ts:

```
class LocalWeather {
  private location: string;
  private temp: number;
  private description: string;
  private humidity: number;
  private icon: string;
  private celsius: number;
  private lat: number;
  private long: number;

  constructor() {

  }

  public async getCoords(): Promise<any> {
    let coords = await fetch('https://geoip.nekudo.com/api').then((response) => response.json());
    this.location = coords.city;
    //console.log(coords)
    this.lat = coords.location.latitude;
    this.long = coords.location.longitude;

    let weatherURL = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${this.lat}&lon=${this.long}&units=imperial&APPID=ef73411c829a4563b61b64e76cb72976`;

    this.getWeatherData(weatherURL);

  }

  private async getWeatherData(url: string): Promise<any> {
    let weatherData = await fetch(url).then((result => result.json()));

    this.icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
    this.temp = weatherData.main.temp;
    this.description = weatherData.weather[0].description;
    this.humidity = weatherData.main.humidity;

    this.handleBackgroundImg();
    this.displayWeather();
  }

  private handleBackgroundImg(): void {
    let weather = document.querySelector(".weather") as HTMLElement;


    switch (this.icon) {
      case "01d":
        weather.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://imageshack.com/a/img923/5914/C8hAMP.jpg")';

        break;
      case "01n":
        weather.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://imageshack.com/a/img924/3455/slHReo.jpg")';

        break;
      case "02d":
      case "03d":
      case "04d":
        weather.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://imageshack.com/a/img922/8471/LF0cGZ.jpg")';

        break;
      case "02n":
      case "03n":
      case "04n":
        weather.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://imageshack.com/a/img923/7048/Ot7l6k.jpg")';

        break;
      case "09d":
      case "10d":
        weather.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://imageshack.com/a/img921/375/RMia6h.jpg")';

        break;
      case "09n":
      case "10n":
        weather.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://imageshack.com/a/img922/1227/Lf4qc2.jpg")';

        break;
      case "11d":
      case "11n":
        weather.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://imageshack.com/a/img924/2258/h4eNcE.jpg")';

        break;
      case "13d":
        weather.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://imageshack.com/a/img922/3753/cEf7xg.jpg")';

        break;
      case "13n":
        weather.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://imageshack.com/a/img923/1196/G2MDy6.jpg")';

        break;
      case "50d":
      case "50n":
        weather.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://imageshack.com/a/img921/8166/H0mO7r.jpg")';

        break;

    }
  }

  private displayWeather(): void {
    let locationSelect = document.querySelector(".location") as HTMLElement;
    let tempSelect = document.querySelector(".temp") as HTMLElement;
    let newI = document.createElement('i');
    let descSelect = document.querySelector(".desc") as HTMLElement;
    let humidSelect = document.querySelector(".humid") as HTMLElement;

    newI.classList.add('wi', 'wi-fahrenheit');
    locationSelect.textContent = `Location: ${this.location}`;
    tempSelect.textContent = `The temperature is ${Math.round(this.temp)} `;
    tempSelect.appendChild(newI);
    descSelect.textContent = `Description: ${this.description.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${this.description.slice(1)}`;
    humidSelect.textContent = `Humidity: ${Math.round(this.humidity)}%`;

    this.handleEvents();
  }

  private handleEvents(): void {
    let fahBtn = document.querySelector(".fah1");
    let temperature = document.querySelector(".temp");
    let newI = document.createElement("i");
    let celBtn = document.querySelector(".cel2");

    fahBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      temperature.textContent = `The temperature is ${Math.round(this.temp)} `;
      newI.classList.remove("wi-celsius");
      newI.classList.add("wi", "wi-fahrenheit");
      let classes = newI.classList;

      temperature.appendChild(newI);

    });

    celBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.celsius = Math.round((this.temp - 32) * 5 / 9);
      temperature.textContent = `The temperature is ${this.celsius} `;
      let classes = newI.classList;
      newI.classList.remove("wi-fahrenheit");
      newI.classList.add("wi", "wi-celsius");

      temperature.appendChild(newI);


    });

  }

}
let weather = new LocalWeather();
weather.getCoords();
```

Please let me know of any anti-patterns you see. I appreciate any tips!

Here is the github: [https://github.com/capozzic1/local_weather_app_v2](https://github.com/capozzic1/local_weather_app_v2/tree/1d19bacd2ddee5cbe608ca3c8316390a57d2f027)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few random suggestions:

---

How come does the code work if the promise is unhandled?! Should be something like `new LocalWeather().getCoords().then(result => {  }).catch(error => { });`

---

Use `const` instead of `let` whenever possible.

---

IMO, lookup-based logic should be expressed as one. Using `switch` is inappropriate.

```
  private iconToImage = {
    '01d': 'img923/5914/C8hAMP.jpg',
    '01n': 'img924/3455/slHReo.jpg',
    '02d': 'img922/8471/LF0cGZ.jpg',
    '03d': 'img922/8471/LF0cGZ.jpg',
    '04d': 'img922/8471/LF0cGZ.jpg',
    '02n': 'img923/7048/Ot7l6k.jpg',
    '03n': 'img923/7048/Ot7l6k.jpg',
    '04n': 'img923/7048/Ot7l6k.jpg',
    '09d': 'img921/375/RMia6h.jpg',
    '10d': 'img921/375/RMia6h.jpg',
    '09n': 'img922/1227/Lf4qc2.jpg',
    '10n': 'img922/1227/Lf4qc2.jpg',
    '11d': 'img924/2258/h4eNcE.jpg',
    '11n': 'img924/2258/h4eNcE.jpg',
    '13d': 'img922/3753/cEf7xg.jpg',
    '13n': 'img923/1196/G2MDy6.jpg',
    '50d': 'img921/8166/H0mO7r.jpg',
    '50n': 'img921/8166/H0mO7r.jpg',
  };
  private handleBackgroundImg(): void {
    const weather = document.querySelector(".weather") as HTMLElement;
    const toUrl = imagePath => `url("http://imageshack.com/a/${imagePath}")`;
    weather.style.backgroundImage = toUrl(this.iconToImage[this.icon]);
  }
```

---

Since you're using `await`/`async` (which are great), I recommend being consistent about using `await` carefully. Example:

```
  public async getCoords(): Promise<any> {
    const coords = await fetch('https://geoip.nekudo.com/api').then((response) => response.json());
    this.location = coords.city;
    this.lat = coords.location.latitude;
    this.long = coords.location.longitude;

    const weatherURL = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${this.lat}&lon=${this.long}&units=imperial&APPID=ef73411c829a4563b61b64e76cb72976`;
    return await this.getWeatherData(weatherURL);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
 // Missing in source...
  }
```

---

`Lat`, `long`, `coord` should be spelled out. Shortening does is not helpful.

Also, you probably don't even need to have all three fields (`location`, `lat`, `long`). In your particular case, it seems to be more reasonable to just have a field for the `fetch()` call result:

```
this.coordinates = await fetch('https://geoip.nekudo.com/api')
                           .then(response => response.json());
```

---

On contrary, the results of `document.querySelector(...)` are the great candidates for "caching" in the object fields. That's because both DOM access and manipulation are expensive operations.

---

Constructor is empty, therefore is redundant. Just remove it until it's not needed.

---

If you have `addEventListener()` in your code, you should have the corresponding `removeEventListener()` as well. Otherwise, you get a memory leak and unnecessary CPU cycles.